# Why does using more threads results in slower runtime?

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, ubuntu, openmp

I am running Ubuntu on a machine with 32 CPUs (1 socket, 16 cores per socket, 2 threads per core).

I have a std::vector containing ~100-1000 objects and I am trying to parallelize a for loop which reads data from each object in the vector and writes to a file to log the state of each object. There is one file for each object. I've played around with `omp_set_num_threads(8)` and discovered that there is a sweet spot of around 8 threads. If I increase or decrease the number of threads the runtime performance will decrease. Given that I have 32 available CPUs I am not sure why increasing the thread count above 8 decreases runtime performance. I know many similar questions have been asked previously but I cannot seem to find a solution to my particular issue.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <experimental/filesystem>
#include <omp.h>
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;  

void log() {
    omp_set_num_threads(8);

    // Log all object states
    if(this->logstate){
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for(auto i = vObject.begin(); i < vObject.end(); ++i)   {
            fs::path filename = (*i)->get_filename();
            std::ofstream OutputFile;
            OutputFile.open(filename, std::ios::app);
            OutputFile << std::setw(30) << (*i)->get_EPOCH() << std::setw(20) << std::scientific << std::setprecision(5) << (*i)->get_state() << std::endl;
            OutputFile.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a wild guess: with more than 8 threads, you'll have more than 8 'processes' writing to disk contemporarily. Might cause some bottleneck

Comment: My guess is you can only write to 8 files simultaneously.

Comment: A vector with only 100-1000 objects in it is small enough to iterate over single-threaded without noticing. Even doing file-handling for each object single-threaded would be quite quick. Especially considering the possible IO contention from multiple threads competing for the same device.

Comment: Creating and destroying threads has a cost. Switching between threads has a cost. Synchronization between threads has a cost. 

Adding threads is *not* a magical silver bullet that will speed things up. If there is not enough parallelism in the problem to overcome the overhead of using threads, then you may very well slow down your code by adding more threads.

Comment: You didn't give any time measures. If the whole procedure takes less than a magnitude of a few seconds you'll start to lose adding more threads than 8 for reasons explained by Some dude and Jesper.

Comment: @NathanOliver Presumably this is a restriction of the OS? Is there anyway to check this?

Comment: A thread context switch accomplishes nothing but takes 2 (or 3 orders) of magnitude more time than a function call.  A function call can be invoked 10 to 100 times (making progress on the overall effort each call) in the time of 1 context switch (where no progress was made).  On my machine, one test of a context switch  (where each run of the thread does a trivial effort) reports 352 ns per switch.  A simple function call (doing the trivial effort) takes 21 ns.  Avoid context switches ... try to get each thread to run continuously.  Avoid thread synchronization.

Comment: Is it that lot of little files are written to same media? There is likely some "master file table" of file system that can't be updated concurrently and so over 8 threads just add more overhead but can do nothing in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

> I am running Ubuntu on a machine with 32 CPUs (1 socket, 16 cores per socket, 2 threads per core).

**A thread is not a CPU.** A core isn't even really a CPU; cores can each execute code independently, but they all share a single memory bus and various other resources.

So, you've got 32 threads running on 16 cores all sharing a single bus. At some point there's going to be contention for something, and that means that a lot of those threads have to sit around and wait. More threads -> more contention -> more waiting.

Now, we can all make educated guesses about where the resource contention might be — is it the file system, the memory bus, or something else? But we don't know much about your system and what else might be going on, so that's probably pointless. Profiling your code running on more threads to see where it's doing a lot of waiting could suggest some answers. Just keep in mind that those answers are likely to be specific to your current situation; if you change the computational work that needs to be done for each object, or change the way the output is collected, etc., that'll likely affect where the sweet spot is.